Command Prompt (cmd.exe) cannot find the internal commands 'FOR' or 'IF' when the command name is called through a variable inside of a FOR command
ISSUE
Command Prompt (cmd.exe) cannot find the internal commands 'FOR' or 'IF' when the command name is called through a variable inside of a FOR command.
Example Command
for /f %a in ("FOR") do %a /?

Error
'FOR' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Additional Details
• In the example command, it is attempting to run the command FOR /? inside of a FOR command by using a variable to call the command.
• The issue occurs when any FOR command or any IF command is called through a variable inside of a FOR command's command section.
• It does not matter if the variable is a FOR command variable (such as %a), or a regular variable (such as !var!).
• If the command is called without using a variable, the command successfully runs inside the FOR command.

TROUBLESHOOTING
• I attempted to run the command in a batch file. I substituted the FOR variable %%a for %a in the batch file and received the same error.
• If the variable is set inside of the command section of the FOR loop, it fails to run the FOR command with the same error.
for /f %a in ("AnyString") do set x=for /?&!x!

• If the variable is set before the FOR command, and the variable is called without delayed expansion, the command succeeds.
set x=for /?
for /f %a in ("AnyString") do set x=for /?&%x%

• The following command demonstrates that, for the commands found in the HELP command, this issue only applies to the commands FOR and IF. The GRAFTABL command will also error out, but this command was removed from cmd.exe years ago. Additionally, DISKPART doesn't support the /? parameter. I suggest hitting "no" when it prompts for UAC elevation. After this, it will output "Access is denied."
echo off&for /f %a in ('help^|findstr /R /C:"^.[ABCDEFGHIJLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]"') do %a /?>nul


WORKAROUND
If you prepend the command with cmd /c in order to run it in a new process, it will work with variables.
for /f %a in ("FOR") do cmd /c %a /?


This question should include more details and clarify the problem. Specifically, the separation of error and user commentary, is difficult to identify. I can’t tell the difference between (explanation, error, and commentary)

In this situation it may be a case of "less is more", or perhaps "different is better". Like Ramhound mentioned, you have what appears to be tangential commentary and some ramblings, and some content in there. I recommend that you start by cutting out everything that is not the specific error, then adding in details that are very closely connected to the error, illustrating and illuminating it, and leave everything else out.

Another case of "it's time to switch to PowerShell"

Some points to consider:


Defining a variable without using set "_var=Strings" and additional commands isn’t recommended, so try using that and see the result.

set "x=for /?"
for /f %a in ("AnyString") do set "x=for /?"& call %%x%%



For reading a value or executing a variable in the same line where you defined it, I suggest trying call %% _var %%

 set "_variable=SomeValue" & call %%_variable%%.



Your code will list and execute files in alphabetical order, and at some point, it will run DiskPart.exe. At that moment, the for loop won’t work as expected, and that’s why you're seeing the error message.



You can avoid this by using if not /i "%~a" == "DiskPart.exe" "%~a" /?.



Once Diskpart.exe is running, anything that follows in your loop won't be processed because those commands don’t exist within the [ console: DiskPart>_] of DiskPart.



Until you type exit, the commands in the "for" loop won’t apply to
DiskPart, because a new window opens, and you clicked "[yes]" to run
with admin privileges, so, don't do that with DiskPart.exe, since your
script isn't designed to modify disks/partitions... at least I assume
so.



This explains why you have the behavior of functioning in:


for /f %a in ("FOR") do cmd /c %a /?




If you’re looking for more comprehensive help on both internal and external commands, I recommend using the allhelp.bat script available on Rob van der Woude's Scripting Pages. This script will return each command along with its corresponding help text in a well-structured HTML format. However, keep in mind that at some point, you may need to respond with [NO] for executable commands like RegEdit and DiskPart.



At the end of the generated HTML page, you will find the credits:


This HTML file was generated by:
AllHelp.bat, Version 1.40 for Windows NT 4 / 2000 / XP
Written by Rob van der Woude
http://www.robvanderwoude.com




Don’t worry about it being designed for older versions of Windows; while you may encounter some error messages, they won’t impact the functionality of your system or the resulting HTML.


Note 1.: There is no /? argument option for RegEdit, DiskPart, and other commands that will be listed with help /?.

Note 2.: When you see the message: "Access is denied" it means that some commands listed (whether exclusive to the console or not) require administrative credentials to be executed in the active window where they were invoked (the current Command Prompt window). If these credentials are not provided, you will receive this message.


An A-Z Index of Windows CMD commands /help online


call %%_var%% is a good trick to know, thank you! And yeah, I do hit no on the UAC prompt when it gets to DiskPart, since it doesn't support the /? switch.
The main reason I've posted this question is because I'm simply curious what is causing the behavior. I can't think of any possible reason it simply can't find the command when it is called through the variable, when it seems to work with all other commands besides FOR and IF.
